# How can I make webshot take a picture of my fully loaded app instead of only its startup?

Tags: r, shiny, webshot

I'm writing a Shiny tutorial in RMarkdown, and am running the app as it is built, but taking screenshots using [webshot](https://wch.github.io/webshot/). As the data for the app is somewhat large, and I'm plotting maps, the whole thing takes 2-4 seconds to load all of the images. So I added a delay to `appshot()`. But, I still get outputs of only the app before plotting the data.

```
appshot(io_app, "shiny_figs/io_app.jpeg",
        vwidth = 800,
        vheight = 800,
        delay = 25)
```

Actually, it's a hair stranger, I get a blank plot. Which is what happens while the app starts up and filters the data the the appropriate settings.

[image: Shiny app from webshot::appshot() with no plot]

What is wrong here, and how can it be fixed? I've tried longer delays (45 seconds) and no dice....